# Зачем нужен оператор pass?

Tags: python, синтаксис

Для чего в python используется конструкция `pass`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Синтаксис `Python` требует, чтобы у некоторых операторов обязательно было тело: класс, функция, условие и т. д. Но иногда необходимо, чтобы там ничего не выполнялось. В таком случае подставляют `pass`.

***Практические кейсы использования:***

- Создание пользовательского класса на основе другого

  Актуально там, где имя класса несёт смысл (исключения, модели БД и т. п.):

  ```py
  class MyException(Exception): 
      pass
  ```
- Декорирование:

  ```py
  @decorator
  class MyClass(OtherClass):
      pass
  ```

  ```
  @decorator
  def f():
      pass
  ```
- Создание методов абстрактного класса:

  ```py
  class MyABC(ABC):
      @abstractmethod
      def method(self):
          pass
  ```
- Обработка исключений:

  ```py
  try:
      f()
  except:
      pass
  ```

Comment: А в питоне интерфейсы есть?

Comment: @Qwertiy Скорее да, чем нет. Можно реализовать с помощью модуля [abc](http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html). Спасибо за комментарий, хороший пример для использования `pass`.

Answer (score 6):

Pass в Python'е это заглушка, то есть, допустим, у вас есть код, который вы планируете дописать, но хотите отложить это по каким -то причинам, или ещё не придумали, что будет в коде.

Answer (score 2):

*Оператор pass*

Оператор pass ничего не делает. Фактически, это такая заглушка для объектов.

Например, pass может помочь в ситуации, когда нужно прописать структуру скрипта. Его можно ставить в циклах, функциях, классах. И это не будет влиять на исполнение кода.

Пример использования pass:

```
for num in range(5):
       if num < 3:
         pass
       else:
         print(num)
```